# Laravel change models table right before query

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I need to change the queried table from a Laravel-model right before the query begins.

Normally you make a query like this:

```
ExampleModel::where('column_name', =, 'value')->get();
```

For one case I want to use a view-table which contains information from multiple tables combined in one view.

Therefore I need to switch the table of `ExampleModel` only for this one situation, e.g.:

```
ExampleModel::table('my_view')->where(...)->get();
```

It is not an option to use `DB::table('my_view')->where(...)->get()` because of several local scopes which need to be applied on `ExampleModel`.

As I could see, there are the following options:

1. somehow change the models table-name on the fly (as shown above)
2. Create a new Model used only in this use case which has the view defined as model-table
3. write all my scopes into a chained `DB`-command

Are there any other options?

Comment: I dont understand why you NEED to use the same model for this. I assume the 2 models you're talking about have a relationship with eachother or something? In that case, you can use https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships . Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The laravel way to Handle this would be to have a dedicated model for your view, with Scopes applying to each of the relevant models :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class AgeScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where('age', '>', 200);
    }
}
```

Then in your ExampleModel AND you MyView Model

```php
 protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new AgeScope);
    }
```

So that when you want to edit a scope it will be reflected on each of your queries

BUT

You will allways know if your model is from your view_table or from you example_model table.

If you need to have some accessor or function used by both, I recomand you to put them in a Trait and use them on both Models

```php
trait ExampleModelTrait
{
   getTestAttribute(){
      return strtolower($this->column_name);
   }
}
```

and then

```php
use ExampleModelTrait;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this stuff by passing table name to **setTable()** method for example :

```
$user = new Users();
$user->setTable('customers');
$user->where(id,1)
...
```

Comment: He is asking before query not model, the `setTable()` will not work when you are using Query Builder.